# I use chardet to test encode , but i got error

Tags: python, python-3.x, chardet

```
import chardet 
a='haha'
print(chardet.detect(a))
```

> TypeError: Expected object of type bytes or bytearray, got: < class 'str'>

I just type code from tutorial.
I really can not figure out what wrong happended.

Comment: Nothing has been encoded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To convert a string to a byte...

Change:

```
a = 'haha'
```

To:

```
a = b'haha'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use

```
a='haha'
print(chardet.detect(a.encode()))
```